# BeautifulSoup - proper way of dealing with self-closing tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an html file with some self-closing tags, but BeautifulSoup doesn't like them.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '<head><meta content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta charset="utf-8"></head>'
doc = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print doc.prettify()
```

prints

```
<head>
 <meta content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type">
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 </meta>
</head>
```

Must I manually check if each tag is self-closing and modify appropriately, or is there a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you may already know, you can specify different parsers that `BeautifulSoup` would use internally. And, as noted in `BeautifulSoup` [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers):

> There are also differences between HTML parsers. If you give Beautiful
>   Soup a perfectly-formed HTML document, these differences won’t matter.
>   One parser will be faster than another, but they’ll all give you a
>   data structure that looks exactly like the original HTML document.
>
> But **if the document is not perfectly-formed, different parsers will
>   give different results**.

In this particular case, both `lxml` and `html5lib` produce two separate `meta` tags:

```
In [4]: doc = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
In [5]: print(doc.prettify())
<html>
 <head>
  <meta content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 </head>
</html>

In [6]: doc = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
In [7]: print(doc.prettify())
<html>
 <head>
  <meta content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```